# Google Maps iOS + Storyboard + Segue = Crash

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps, uistoryboardsegue

What I do in my app is following:

I load some data into the core data and when that is finished app needs to segue to the next view (google map)

`[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"loadMap" sender:self];`

but I get this error

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'GMSThreadException', reason: 'All calls to the Google Maps SDK for iOS must be made from the UI thread'`

If I do all of this but make a segue with tap on a button everything works fine.

Google map view controller in storyboard has one GMSMapView view outlet with init code

```
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:45.331875
                                                            longitude:14.450455
                                                                 zoom:14];

    self.mapView.camera = camera;

    GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
    marker.position = camera.target;
    marker.title = @"Test title";
    marker.snippet = @"Lorem ipsum...";
    marker.map = self.mapView;
```

Can anybody help me here? How can I load view controller with google maps programmatically using storyboard?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The exception seems to be indicating that you're trying to perform a segue in the background thread. To stop it from crashing, you need to use the main thread instead. Wrap your `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` as follows to use the main thread:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"loadMap" sender:self];
});
```

Answer (score 3):

For Swift:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {})
```

Toss the code in those curlies...